# Is there easier way to fill this hole automatically?

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

[image]

Hello, I want to fill this hole like this :

[image]

Not like this :

[image]

I usually use "F" to fill hole and Knife tool to make it be along with edge lines manually,

But if there is easier way to fill this hole with edge lines automatically, pleas let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm don't think there's any automatic way to do it, once you've filled, use the knife

Comment: Are you trying to create a room? And do you only have the walls or is there a floor as well (can't see it in the screenshots)? If so, didn't you create all those edges with loop cuts? Then the floor is already cut like the ceiling should be... why not select all the floor faces, Shift D, then Z to duplicate and move upwards. Then snap to the top vertices, select all, M > Merge > By Distance and you're finished. I might be wrong, I would suspect you have created it like that...